# Force IE to display csv file rather than opening download dialog

Tags: internet-explorer

When I enter this URL

http://www.google.com/trends/trendsReport?hl=en-US&geo=US&export=1&q=stack%20overflow

in Internet Explorer, the .csv file is downloaded. Is there a way to force IE to display the text of the file rather than opening a download dialog box? (I cannot use another web browser for this.)

Answer (score 0):

Check that the .csv type is associated with Internet Explorer.  I suspect it is associated with some other program at present.  Steps may vary depending on what OS you are using, but try something like this:

- Via file Explorer View/Options/File Types
- Look for CSV file type click Open
- Then Edit button to change the default

I hope that helps!

Also see [this post](http://www.winxptutor.com/iedocs.htm), which references the

> "Browse in same window option"

so you may need to check this option too.

Comment: Thanks, but the download dialog box still opens. The .csv was associated with Excel, and now the dialog just says it will open it with "Application", but IE isn't displaying the file.

Comment: Try using a tool like Fiddler or HttpWatch to see the headers of the HTTP response so you can see the exact mime type being returned in response to your HTTP request.  Then check that against this article to see if a registry value needs to be updated: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx